# Automatic renaming of files

Tags: operating-system, rename, stata, batch-rename, stata-macros

I am trying to batch rename many files within the same folder on my operating system.

I have a dataset with two variables: `oldname` and `newname`.

There are more file names in the dataset then actual files that need to be renamed so I would like to build something that matches the file with the observation in the dataset, renames the matched file, and then moves it to the new location.

For example, I have a three files in a location:

```
filepath/to/my/files/file1.jpg
filepath/to/my/files/file2.jpg
filepath/to/my/files/file3.jpg
```

A dataset with string variables:

```
Dataset
     newname     oldname    
a    pink        files/file1.jpg
b    blue        files/file4.jpg
c    purple      files/file6.jpg
d    green       files/file3.jpg
e    red         files/file2.jpg
```

Here is the desired output of the program:

```
filepath/for/matches/pink.jpg
filepath/for/matches/red.jpg
filepath/for/matches/green.jpg
```

Do I need to use the `!` operator to achieve what i want?

---

**EDIT:**

So far, I've got a method of moving the matches but not for renaming them:

```
global dir "/filepath"
global old "$dir/to/my/"
global new "$dir/for/matches"
ssc install mvfiles

preserve 
keep if oldname!=.
foreach i in oldname{
    mvfiles, infolder($old) outfolder($new) match(substr(`i',6,9))
}
restore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. You can achieve what you want by simply using the `copy` command.

The following should work:

```
clear

input str1 letter str10 newname  str15 oldname    
"a"    "pink"        "files/file1"
"b"    "blue"        "files/file4"
"c"    "purple"      "files/file6"
"d"    "green"       "files/file3"
"e"    "red"         "files/file2"
end

local inpath "filepath/to/my/files/"
local outpath "different/filepath/for/matches/"
local files : dir "`inpath'" files "*.jpg"

local obs = _N

foreach fil of local files {
    forvalues i = 1 / `obs' {
        local oldname = oldname[`i']
        if substr("`fil'", 1, strpos("`fil'", ".") - 1) == substr("`oldname'", 7, .) {
            local newname = newname[`i']
            copy "`inpath'`fil'" " `outpath'`newname'.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

Just replace the local macros `inpath` and `outpath` with your desired paths.

Note that If you also want to delete the file after you copy it, then just add the following after the `copy` command:

```
erase "`inpath'`fil'"
```